# How to align items horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

Please help me put these boxes next to each other and not on top of each other. This should be so simple, but for some reason I am not able to figure it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/DShepherd79/6qsg8g1L/2/

```
<body>
   <div class="horAlign">
      <a class="rTableCell processMap"></a>
      <a class="rTableCell sharepoint"></a>
   </div>   
</body>

.horAlign{
   background-color:black;
   width: 500px;
   position: absolute;
}

.rTableCell{
   padding:25px;
}

/*images Start Here*/
.processMap {
   background:#08F80D no-repeat center;
   display:block;
   height:50px;
   width:50px;
}

.sharepoint{
   background-color:purple; no-repeat center;
   display:block;
   height:50px;
   width:50px;
}

/*Hover Images Start Here*/
.processMap:hover {
   background-color:red; no-repeat center;
}

.sharepoint:hover {
   background-color:blue; no-repeat center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `display:block` to `display:inline-block`

See https://jsfiddle.net/6qsg8g1L/3/

Comment: Thanks, now how can I center them in the given space?

Comment: Add `text-align: center;` in `.horAlign`